# Apache chronos: how to access web ui

Tags: apache, mesos, mesosphere

I have followed https://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/#example-run-scripts .
 What is the url of the web ui?

Answer (score 2):

The Chronos Web UI is available via port `4400` (same as the REST API) on the host you've launched it via `java -cp chronos.jar ...`. See also the tutorial [Exercise 18 – Advanced Usage of Chronos](https://open.mesosphere.com/advanced-course/advanced-usage-of-chronos/) for more ways to use Chronos.

Comment: One could also use the flag `--http_port` to configure the actual port if port 4400 is not desired. Also, I'd recommend to set the FQDN as `--hostname` to be able to open the UI via the Master's Frameworks list.